# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../../../vue-temp/vue-editor-bridge' in 'D:\laravel projects\codeGram\resources\js\components'

Tags: node.js, laravel, vue.js

i am using laravel + vuejs to do the follow and unfollow button of instagram clone , but i get this error i did everything i could, checked the config.js , deleted the module package and again run the npm install but it didnt work here is my code

```
<template>
    <div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary ml-4" @click="followUser" v-text="buttonText">Folloq</button>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import func from '../../../vue-temp/vue-editor-bridge';

    export default {
        props: ['userId', 'follows'],

        watch: {
            status: function() {
                this.buttonText = (this.status) ? 'Unfollow' : 'Follow';
            }
        },

        data: function () {
            return {
                status: this.follows,
                buttonText: this.follows ? 'Unfollow' : 'Follow'
            }
        },

        methods: {
            followUser() {
                 axios.post('/follow/' + this.userId)
                    .then(response => {
                        this.status = ! this.status;

                        console.log(response.data);
                    })
                    
                    .catch(errors => {
                        if (errors.response.status == 401){
                            window.location = '/login';
                        }
                    });
            }
        },
    }
</script>
```

my code in the view in index.blade.php for the button is

```
 <follow-button user-id="{{$user->id}}"  follows="{{ $follows }}"></follow-button>
```

route is
Route::post('follow/{user}','App\Http\Controllers\FollowsController@store');

full error

ERROR in ./resources/js/components/FollowButton.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js& (./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js??clonedRuleSet-5[0].rules[0].use[0]!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js??vue-loader-options!./resources/js/components/FollowButton.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&) 7:0-55
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../../../vue-temp/vue-editor-bridge' in 'D:\laravel projects\codeGram\resources\js\components'

Comment: The errors tells you that the relative file path does not actually point to a module. What is your directory structure? If you use an IDE, try using the auto-import feature and see if the `import` statement is updated?

Comment: can u put your folder structure ?

Answer (score 14):

VS Code automatically added in your code line like:

```
import func from 'vue-editor-bridge'
```

Find it in your code and remove it. Done!

Comment: It's the same answer as mine.

Answer (score 13):

I assume you don't want to use this at all:

```
import func from '../../../vue-temp/vue-editor-bridge';
```

Vscode imports this 'func' from a module when you want to autocomplete while writing function. This is totally annoying and if anybody knows how to turn it off, you would be my personal hero!

Answer (score 1):

I faced this problem too, and it happens because, instead of typing complete `function` in the code, I used the autocomplete version of `function` which was `func` and as func is a totally different thing in Vue, as compared to function, Vue just put `import func from 'vue-editor-bridge'`.

Just change the word `func` to `function` and remove this import inside the script tag and it will be ok.

That's how it works for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you are in vue and your error starts like this 'Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http' ...' installing `url-loader` will do the trick. Just install it using npm.
`npm install --save-dev url-loader`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).